# How do I create an array of image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I read one by one images from a directory and I wish to create an array of images with that to pass to my mexFunction that processes these images. What I am tried so far is not working.  Let say I have 100 images 256x256 when I do

```
 directory = uigetdir; fileList = dir(directory); imageVolume= [];

for idx = 3:numel(fileList)

     tempImage = imread(fullfile(directory, fileList(idx).name));
    imageVolume= [imageVolume tempImage]; 
 end
```

Whenever I do that, I don't get an array of 256x256xn, instead I just get an image of 256x(256*n), which is not what I want.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cell arrays as @bjornsen suggested works. If you would rather not use cell arrays, you can use 3 dimensional matrices:

```
imageVolume(:,:,idx) = tempImage;
```

You must be sure, though, that all images are the same size. Otherwise, you're better off using cell arrays.

Comment: Yes, but third dimension is for image RGB channel, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Use Cell Arrays.  Assuming the rest of your code is right:

```
for idx = 3:numel(fileList)
     tempImage{idx} = imread(fullfile(directory, fileList(idx).name));
end
```